# NullPointerException in Eclipse Juno opening ANY file

Tags: eclipse

Was installing and uninstalling some plugins and now ALL file types in ALL projects break with this error in log - even those that previously worked.  Any ideas?  Is there any way to fix it other than reinstalling Eclipse?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2013-10-17 12:55:28.570
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3063)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$22(WorkbenchPage.java:2969)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2951)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2947)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2911)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2902)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
```